# iOS 12 being more aggressive about closing my app?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I wrote a stat tracker for skiing / snowboarding that was working just fine last season.  This season I'm having the hardest time keeping the app alive even though I'm setup to receive background location updates.

Here are some of the tasks that are running in the background on timers:

- Parsing arrays / dictionaries and performing calculations
- Receiving and sending data to firebase
- Recording data to CoreData

As long I have cell signal things have a better chance of staying alive but no guarantee.

Did something change in iOS 12 vs 11?

Here's my code for starting location updates:

```swift
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
locationManager.activityType = .other
locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
            
locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
locationManager.showsBackgroundLocationIndicator = true
            
locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

I've tried `locationManagerDidPauseLocationUpdates` to restart location updates if iOS tried to kill it, changing the activity type, changing the accuracy, nothing seems to work although changing the activity type to other did extend the amount of time before the app dies so I thought `locationManagerDidPauseLocationUpdates` would restart it but no dice.

Any other ideas on keeping things alive while recording?

I've also tried checking for memory leaks

Screenshot of Info.plist:

[image]

Comment: You can't rely on timers in the background.  You should either do work in response to the location update or store data locally for processing when your app returns to the foreground.  You could also store data locally and use background refresh to process data and upload it periodically.

Comment: What about info.plist? Did you setup background modes there?

Comment: I double checked but just in case I posted the screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I don't know why but after some experimentation and moving things around I seem to have fixed it.

I had CllocationManager as a singleton and moved it to a struct as I'm sharing it between multiple VCs as to not instantiate it more than once.

I then moved

```
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.activityType = .other
    locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
    locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
    locationManager.showsBackgroundLocationIndicator = true
```

out of its own function and into viewDidLoad() which still didn't work so I moved it to viewDidAppear() and now my app has been running for 8 hours without a hiccup.  I'm not sure if the way I was sharing the location manager before was causing a second instantiation and a reset of the location manager settings to default which would cause locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically to become true (not sure just guessing)